# Bash script to find included files in C code

Tags: bash, shell

I've got the following shell script (let say `get_includes.sh`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
includes=($(grep ^#include file.c | grep -o '"[^"]\+"' | tr -d '"'))
echo "0: ${includes[0]}"
echo "1: ${includes[1]}"
```

which aims at finding relative include files in source code file.

So for given file like this (`file.c`):

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It'll return the following results which are correct:

```
$ ./get_includes.sh 
0: foo.h
1: bar.h
```

The code works as expected, however `shellcheck` complains about the following issues:

```
$ shellcheck get_includes.sh 

    In get_includes.sh line 2:
    includes=($(grep ^#include file.c | grep -o '"[^"]\+"' | tr -d '"'))
              ^-- SC2207: Prefer mapfile or read -a to split command output (or quote to avoid splitting).

    For more information:
      https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2207 -- Prefer mapfile or read -a to spli...
      https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2236 -- Use -n instead of ! -z.
```

So:

- I can't quote command substitution, as I expect the command to expand to an array.
- I don't want to ignore the warning, I'd like to correct it.

I'm using Bash 4.

**So, how I can correct the above line to satisfy `shellcheck`?** If possible, I'd like to keep it in one-liner.

---

I've tried the following approaches which failed:

```
$ (grep ^#include file.c | grep -o '"[^"]\+"' | read -a myarr; echo $myarr)
(nothing is printed)
$ (grep ^#include file.c | grep -o '"[^"]\+"' | mapfile myarr; echo $myarr)
(nothing is printed)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### ... so what's going on?

> ```
> $ (grep ^#include file.c | grep -o '"[^"]\+"' | read -a myarr; echo $myarr)
> (nothing is printed)
> $ (grep ^#include file.c | grep -o '"[^"]\+"' | mapfile myarr; echo $myarr)
> (nothing is printed)
> ```

Why doesn't this work? Because [*"each command in a pipeline is executed in its own subshell"*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html). As the page explains, you could enable the `lastpipe` option to have the last element of the pipeline run in the current process. (The page doesn't mention that this will only work when you use it in a script, where job control is not active (as mentioned [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)). It won't work in an interactive shell.)

#### Keep pipelines as short as possible

It's good to use the fewest possible processes in pipelines.
Multiple `grep` in a pipeline are points to look at with suspicion.
You can make the first `grep` work a little harder,
using a stricter pattern, and then you can achieve the same result with 2 processes instead of 3:

```
grep '^#include .*"' file.c | cut -d'"' -f2
```

Comment: What would have worked is `... | { read -a myarr; echo "$myarr"; }` but it would have made for quite ugly code.

Answer (score 0):

After reading more about [SC2207](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2207), the proper syntax would be:

```
mapfile -t includes < <(grep ^#include file.c | grep -o '"[^"]\+"' | tr -d '"')
```